# Starting Flask Server as a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, flask

I want to start a Flask Server that has been created by SwaggerUI as a thread inside another Python script. The command to start it uses the `-m` Flag (`python -m swagger_server`). How can I use the `-m` flag inside a Python script?

I tried using the `runpy` module

```
runpy.run_module('swagger_server')
```

but it just executes and finishes without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Most packages will only run when they are in the `__main__` scope to prevent them from running when they are imported.

`runpy.run_module()` sets `__name__` based on the `run_name` argument:

> `__name__` is set to `run_name` if this optional argument is not `None`, to `mod_name + '.__main__'` if the named module is a package and to the `mod_name` argument otherwise.
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html

You can run your package by setting `run_name` to `__main__`:

```
runpy.run_module('swagger_server', run_name='__main__')
```